# copy typoscript inside files added with addTypoScriptSetup seem not to work

Tags: typo3, typoscript

In my own extension in TYPO3 7.6, I added typoscript via ext_localconf.php:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTypoScriptSetup(
    '<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:EXT:myextension/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.ts">'
);
```

The added typoscript is very simple.
But surprisingly this doesn't work:

```
content < styles.content.get
```

whereas this works:

```
content = CONTENT
content {
  table = tt_content
  select.orderBy = sorting
  select.where = colPos = 0
}
```

It seems to me that copying typoscript-Object generally doesn't work inside files that are included via `ExtensionManagementUtility::addTypoScriptSetup`.

Is that so? And, if yes: Why is that?

Answer (score 3):

You can copy TS objects in included files.

Things to check:

- Does the file `FILE:EXT:myextension/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.ts` exist?
- Is `fluid_styled_content` or `css_styled_content` (whatever you use) installed and the TS loaded?
- Ordering. Was `styles.content.get` defined before your TypoScript is included? Put your line from your ext_localconf.php to the setup part of the template record so it is loaded after the static inclusions.

Comment: And most importantly: go check the backend module "Templates" and its submodule "Template analysor" for the actual order of all TypoScript templates. There's a button called something like "Display full list" or something similar. That's the first thing to check on an issue like that.